# Google Docs python gdata 2.0.16 upload file to existing collection

Tags: python, collections, upload, gdata, google-docs

I have managed to create a simple app which deletes (bypassing the recycle bin) any files I want to.  It can also upload files.  The problem I am having is that I cannot specify which collection the new file should be uploaded to.

```
def UploadFile(folder, filename, local_file, client):
    print "Upload Resource"
    doc = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type='document', title=filename)
    path = _GetDataFilePath(local_file)
    media = gdata.data.MediaSource()
    media.SetFileHandle(path, 'application/octet-stream')
    create_uri = gdata.docs.client.RESOURCE_UPLOAD_URI + '?convert=false'
    collection_resource = folder
    upload_doc = client.CreateResource(doc, create_uri=create_uri, collection=collection_resource, media=media)
    print 'Created, and uploaded:', upload_doc.title, doc.resource_id
```

From what I understand the function CreateResources requires a resource object representing the collection.  How do I get this object?  The variable folder is currently just a string which says 'daily' which is the name of the collection, it is this variable which I need to replace with the collection resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From various sources, snippets and generally stuff all over the place I managed to work this out.  You need to pass a uri to the FindAllResources function (one which I found no mention of in the sample code from gdata).

I have written up in more detail how I managed to upload, delete (bypassing the bin), search for and move files into collections

[here](http://shadowbadger.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/uploading-deleting-bypassing-the-bin-and-searching-for-documents-on-google-docs-with-python-gdata/)